# Can I charge a DC 5V - 2.15 A power bank with an Apple Macbook charger?

Tags: battery, charger

Can I charge the following power bank with a macbook chager?

Power bank input: **DC 5V - 2.15 A**  (Input port: Micro USB)

Macbook charger: Apple 29W USB-C Power Adapter: **5.2V @ 2.4A, 14.5V @ 2A**

(with USB > Micro USB cable)

thanks

Comment: I think that will work, though I am not sufficiently certain that I dare post it as an asnwer. :-)  The thing is, the power adapter will not deliver higher than 5V unless requested to do so by the other side. I have had one guest to my apartment charge his android phone (brand unknown) with a USB-C cable from a macbook charger, and that worked just fine.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks, let's put it another way: in case it doesn't work, is there any risk the power bank burns or get damaged?

Comment: No, I don't think there is much chance of that beyond the risk you *always* have of batteries catching fire: I.e., minimal. But I don't know the details of the specs in sufficient detail to state that authoritatively. To get those answers, you might have better luck elsewhere, as this is more of a generic electronics question than a mac question. But you can think of it this way: When the USB-C standard was put together, *for sure* it would be realised that someone is going to plug a 5V device into a 14V charger. To render that unsafe would just be reckless.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is entirely possible. The power bank accepts standard USB power, and the MacBook charger with USB-C will be just that when you add the USB-C to micro-USB cable.

Note ofcourse that it won't charge faster than the standard charger. Even though the MacBook charger is a 29W charger, it won't charge your power bank at the full rate (instead it will charge at somewhere between 2.6W and 7.8W - most probably at 4.68W).

Comment: Yeah sure speed won't be the same, no problem. But it's good news that it should work. thanks